# the application for project is not installed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2003

I'm opening a solution that was apparently built on Visual Studio 2003 (not sure, I don't know anything about it) and trying to migrate to 2010. When trying to migrate I get the message:

the application for project '' is not installed make sure the application for the project type (.csproj) is installed.

If I open each one of the single projects of the solution they migrate fine but not the solution itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your projects individually migrate fine, then create a new blank visual studio 2010 solution, and add new projects individually (right click on solution->add->existing project)

But I'm not sure that your projects will load fine individually. There are project types that require some additional software to be installed in order to be supported. The most frequent problems I face are old projects built with old versions of asp.net mvc (1 or 2) and I have asp.net mvc 3 installed...or really old projects built with asp.net ajax...In those cases, you have to install that additional software and then import project, or find a tool to upgrade that project type to a newer version.

Answer (score 84):

**Right-click on the project file, then "Reload"**

If your solution opens, but your project is showing as "incompatible", it may need to just reload. This worked for me when running an update from VS, and it did not recognize my `njsproj`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you Jeremy

Comment: Worked fo rme too. Thanks

Comment: The error message in Visual Studio was a bit unhelpful to say mildly. Thank for you for a great tip Jeremy!

Comment: Note:  This doesn't always work.  At least not always without doing something else, first.

Comment: @vapcguy Very true, VS can throw this error for many reasons. Reloading the project file is just one of the fastest things to check first IMHO. :)

Comment: Worked perfectly in VS 2017 as well.

Comment: Wow, worked in 2019 too. So much frustration and the fix is right click--> reload. Wish the error messages were better.

Comment: Worked in VS2019 on 2 projects for me. My host PC and with it the VM it was running rebooted over night and seemingly messed up VS2019. Restored to an earlier VMware snapshot to sort out the VS install, but at least 2 source projects that were open were still "corrupt" - even after using older version of the project and solutions files. This simple reload worked on them.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but it is still occurring in VS 2013.

I had an old VS 2003 web application. I opened it in VS 2013 (Ultimate) and had the error message:

```
Could not find the server on the local machine.
Creating a virtual directory is only supported on the local IIS server
```

along with

```
The application for project is not installed.
```

Yes, I am upgrading, and yes, I don't have some other elements ready. Giving me errors is fine - but why are you not completing the migration/load of the project. I can't fix the other issues if you don't LOAD ANYTHING! You loaded the subprojects, and then you told me that I should choose a later .NET Framework. Great, I did that. So why didn't you just finish loading the main project and let me fix the errors?

Lots of attempts to fix this failed. My final solution, just to get the project loaded was {arrow pierces chest, dies with *Arghhhhhh* on his lips}...

I located the `{project}.csproj` file. I found the `<Reference>` sections. The paths to the .NET Framework components were no longer valid and referred to old versions no longer installed (yeah, upgrading, remember?). I manually changed the paths to refer to .NET Framework 4.5 components. The project still didn't load.

Then I located the `{project}.csproj.webinfo` file. It referred to `http://localhost/{stuff}/{project}.csproj`, so I just set it to `{project}.csproj`. No luck. Then I just renamed the webinfo file to hide it. Eureka, the project was hot!

The project loaded, I got the "You have completed the first step in converting your Visual Studio .NET 2003 web project. To complete the conversion, please select your project in the Solution Explorer and choose the 'Convert to Web Application' context menu item." Which, of course, is not present, but is present as the very last item in the Project menu. Then I got the "This action will add designer and code behind files required for converting Web site projects to Web application projects. Do you want to continue?" You bet your posterior I want to continue! And now I have a project I can actually start to fix.  Thanks, Microsoft, for the informative error messages.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution that worked for Visual Studio 2017.

In Visual Studio, go to **Tools > Extensions and updates**.  At the upper-right search box, search for "integration".  It should come up with Analysis or Diagnostic Tools (or similar).  Click **Disable**, then **Enable**.  Exit the dialog, and close Visual Studio.  Relaunch and open your solution again.  Your projects will still complain they can't be loaded because of incompatibilities, but now you can right-click them individually and select "Reload Project" and they should load fine.

Credit goes to Paul Potter and Paul Shaughnessy at   https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/216061/project-incompatible-application-not-installed.html - I just did the verification work, condensing the information, and delivery :)

Comment: This solution worked for me - VS 2017, opening a solution from 2 years back which was showing the same error as OP. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer as reference for people who landed here for missing ".smproj" file.

This issue can arise due to various project files missing. For me, it was because of ".smproj" file missing which is Project file for SQL Server Analysis Services(SSAS). I re-installed SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) and restarted the Visual studio.
[Originally Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61189366/2871072)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the SSIS or SSAS Extension in "Manage Extension" is disabled in the settings and must be Enabled manually. And then restart Visual Studio

[image: Extensions>Manage Extensions]

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me as wel.

You usualy do really need only to reload project in the solution. But in some cases you maybe:

- didn't install [SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) for VS
- have to enable SQL Server Data Tools manualy in the [Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-using-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2022#manage-extensions-dialog-box)

If you have both things settled then try to reload project again. This happened to me when I moved from VS2019 to VS2022 and extension was somehow disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I am using visual studio 2019 and I was faced with this issue when I reopened my ASP.Net webform App in visual studio after modifying for install SSDT.
this problem happens when Visual studio packages will modify (Especially when SSDT will be installed).

To solve this problem you have to go to you project folder and looking for the folder that named '.vs', this folder is hidden.

Deleting these folder will solve the problem because after that when you will open your project with visual studio, it will create the folder again.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this for those who face issues for SSRS projects in VS2017 from earlier version as this comes up in google search.

In Visual Studio, go to **Tools > Extensions and updates**. Download the below :

**Microsoft Reporting Services Projects

Microsoft RDLC Report Designer**

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS 2017, t the upper-right search box, search Microsoft Integration Services Projects.

```
go to Tools > Extensions and updates.
Enable -"Microsoft Integration Services Projects"
```

This will help to resolve the issue re-launch the SSIS

Answer (score 0):

[image: Disabled extension]

For my case, I disabled this extension and turns out, it is needed.

Enabling it resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2019 Before you try any of the above right click the solution and click "Resolve Errors" no kidding that made my tabular model solution being available again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

For me what worked was a variation of @vapcguy solution.

1. Go to @vapcguy link for Paul Potter and Paul Shaughnessy solution: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/216061/project-incompatible-application-not-installed.html - I
2. Follow comment on Paul Potter's post by Albert Romeo
3. Integration Services Plugin was disabled(as explained before: Goto Tools > Extensions and updates > and search for integration/analysis/reporting and enable application

I had to enable integration services, then reload project.  I don't know why since I've been using the same SSIS project several times a week for months.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).