# Project doesn't open on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to open this project [Link](https://crm2011internalemail.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) using VS2013, but it shows at first "the solution you are opening is bound to source control on the following team foundation server" then when I click on "no" it shows "this project is incompatible with the current version of visual studio" .
Can you please tell me how can I do in order to open this project?

Regards,

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. Which version does not work? 2012? 2013?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010909/this-project-is-incompatible-with-the-current-version-of-visual-studio) might be of help to you.

Comment: @Gábor Bakos Thanks for your quick answer, it doesnt work with all versions ( 2012, 2013) , i see the .sln file that says 'requires 2 projects' and inside the two folders I see .csproj extension :(

Comment: @Christian I cant update the framework of the project ! as it doesn't open it at all

Comment: Running VS 2013 Update 4 I get a different error message: "The application which this project type is based on was not found" - looking that up it basically means I need to have the right SDKs installed, in this case possibly (but I'm not sure) this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded this project. I use VS2012. It said me that it doesnt support this type of project.

I can open SilverlightApplication and workflow projects. But i am not able to open another two projects.
I checked the cproj file and came across this

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Dynamics CRM 2011 Developer Tools\1.0\Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll


  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Dynamics CRM 2011 Developer Tools\1.0\Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll

and this

And after this i suppose that you have to download this Dynamics CRM 2011 Developer Tool and Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004 Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Software Development Kit

And try check this article http://waelhamze.com/2013/06/12/building-the-crm-developer-toolkit-solution-crmpackage-in-the-cloud-tfs-online/