# this project is incompatible with the current edition of visual studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I developed an application into Visual Studio 2012. Now I installed Visual Studio 2015 and run the same application into Visual Studio 2015. but i found an error **"this project is incompatible with the current edition of visual studio"** I searched it again and again and found many solutions but these solutions are not working for me.[image]

Comment: What kind of projects do you have in the solution?

Comment: @Richard what do you mean by what kind of project ?

Comment: May be it's a Xamarin Project or smth else. And these tools were removed from 2012 or just need reinstall

Comment: it is MVC Project

Comment: You don't give details on the edition of Visual Studio you use. The Express edition for example, doesn't allow to open desktop app projects, only Windows Store projects. If you have Express and are trying to open a desktop app project, you might get that error.

Comment: Generally, it should be fine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532477/visual-studio-2015-solutions-backwards-compatibility-with-visual-studio-2013. Give more details about the project

Comment: why voted me down. I stuck into genuine problem and wasting my time to search the solution from previous week. What kind of information you want from me....?

Comment: If you can open the project file in notepad and paste its content as part of the question, then someone might provide an answer. Now you let everyone make a guess, which is ridiculous and I think that's why you have been down voted.

Comment: Try to change .csproj file in your old project. go first create any sample project in VS2015 save it and open this project csproj file and match the data with your sample project .csproj file and update accordingly and then try to load(please make backup first) and check what happens @TittiTowel

Comment: thanks @Rajput may it will help me....

Comment: Yeah check it and let us know

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that I wasn't select Microsoft Web Development during installation period so that whenever I opened my ASP.net MVC project in that installed IDE. It showed me error **this project is incompatible with the current edition of visual studio**. So I updated this installed 2015 Visual Studio by **Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features**. Now it is working

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61189366/2871072) stackoverflow provides better answer for various other project file failures which cause same error as above.