# After upgrading .NET CORE : This project is incompatible with the current version of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-core, .net-core-2.1

So I decided to migrate dotnet core projects from version 1.0.0 to 2.1.4 (the newest). I downloaded the SDK from the official .NET website. When everything was installed, I opened Visual Studio 2015 and was shocked.

All projects (literally all, even those which didn't use Core at all) were not successfully loaded. The error message shown was:

> **“This project is incompatible with the current version of Visual Studio”**

Can you give me some advice for a newbie? I've read this topic: ["This project is incompatible with the current version of Visual Studio"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010909/this-project-is-incompatible-with-the-current-version-of-visual-studio)

However, .csproj file contains this:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Comment: Maybe you need the VS 2017.

Comment: `However, my project file .csproj looks like this: <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>` are you sure that isn't a .NET Framework project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft documentation, you need Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7 or higher for .NET Core 2.1 apps.

If you don't have a license for Visual Studio 2017, you could open it in Visual Studio Code (it's free).