# How do I find type of c# project from Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I've never worked with C# and have been handed a huge piece of legacy code in C#, which I have to make changes to. I'm not sure what the template of the solution is and the solution refuses to run as one of the projects reads

> (incompatible) The application is not installed.

I'm trying to create a new solution and migrate all the existing projects within that solution to see if I can get it to work [(going by this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9264202/2696086) but I'm not sure what the project template should be from the list that Visual Studio provides.

The list currently has these templates:

- WPF App (.NET Framework)
- Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)
- Console App (.NET Core)
- Console App (.NET Framework)
- Class Library (.NET Standard)
- Class Library (.NET Framework)
- ASP.NET Core Web Application
- ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)

...(there are more but I don't think they're the right ones)

I'm not sure what the differences among any of them are. Please tell me how I can learn the project template of the solution that has been given to me.

Comment: I don't think creating a new solution and migrate it is the way to go, have you tried right clicking the project and click on "reload project"?

Comment: @penleychan I did. VS says - Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them.

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using? What's the ToolsVersion/VisualStudioVersion value in the project's .csproj?

Comment: @Flameofudun What is the type of project that's failing to load? You probably don't have the appropriate extension installed to load it. You're not going to magically fix this problem by creating a new solution.

Comment: @JonathonChase I'm using VS 2017. The about vs window says version 15.6.4. I'm not sure how to check the .csproj. I simply opened the .sln file in notepad and at the top it reads VisualStudioVersion 15.0.27428.2015

Comment: @Flameofudun With the solution open, right click the project that won't load and select Edit {projName}.csproj. Look for the `ProjectTypeGuids` entry, it is semi-colon delimited. Reference those values against the list provided by @H.Szczepański. I would suspect something like an earlier MVC version (3 maybe) that no longer comes bundled with the default installers.

Comment: @Flameofudun [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028746/visual-studio-vdproj-is-incompatible) for working with a `vdproj`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check GUID of existing project and compare it to this list :
https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs